# DJIGimbalRotation can use in p4 p 4 pro ,but can't use spark

Tags: dji-sdk

I work on a project that takes photo use DJI ,and I rotate the camera to ground ,and I can take photo use this method

rotation = [DJIGimbalRotation gimbalRotationWithPitchValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-90] rollValue:nil yawValue:nil time:0.01f mode:DJIGimbalRotationModeAbsoluteAngle];

but when I use this method in dpi spark, I got an error and it tells me failed ,how can I make the camera to ground in Spark ,anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The Gimbal pitch value for Spark is [0,-85], so it's not available to set it as -90 and make the camera to ground in Spark using DJI Mobile SDK. You can check the capabilities property to get the pitch rotation range info: https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/Gimbal/DJIGimbal.html?search=capabilities&i=0&#djigimbal_gimbalcapabilities_inline